# Change color of Select component's border and arrow icon Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use a Material UI [Select](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/) component on a dark background:

[image]

But I'm unable to change the color of the drop down icon and underline border to white. I've looked at overriding the styles using classes, and I'm able to change color with the following:

```js
const styles = theme => {
    root: {
       borderBottom: '1px solid white',
    },
    icon: {
       fill: 'white',
    },
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <Select
                value={this.props.value}
                inputProps={{
                    classes: {
                        root: classes.border,
                        icon: classes.icon,
                    },
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem
                    value={this.props.value}
                >
                    Foo
                </MenuItem>
            </Select>   
        )
    }
}
```

However, I cannot seem to set the color of the underline while the Select component is in focus, i.e. with the above code, I get the white underline and icon, but while focus is on the component the underline stays black.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With some help from [Jan-Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8148122/jan-philipp) I got everything colored white, also while the component stays in focus:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    select: {
        '&:before': {
            borderColor: color,
        },
        '&:after': {
            borderColor: color,
        }
    },
    icon: {
        fill: color,
    },
});


class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <Select
                value="1"
                className={{classes.select}}
                inputProps={{
                    classes: {
                        icon: classes.icon,
                    },
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem value="1"> Foo 1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="2"> Foo 2</MenuItem>
            </Select>   
        )
    }
}
```

Not a very pretty solution to getting the right contrast, but it does the job.

**Edit**
The above answer is missing some code, and is also missing the hover color, as suggested by @Sara Cheatham. See updated hooks based solution:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    select: {
        '&:before': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
        '&:after': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
        '&:not(.Mui-disabled):hover::before': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
    },
    icon: {
        fill: 'white',
    },
    root: {
        color: 'white',
    },
})

export const MyComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <Select
            className={classes.select}
            inputProps={{
                classes: {
                    icon: classes.icon,
                    root: classes.root,
                },
            }}
            value='1'
        >
            <MenuItem value='1'> Foo 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='2'> Foo 2</MenuItem>
        </Select>
    )
}
```

Comment: The variable `styles` in this example is unused.  Is there something missing here?

Comment: I think this is missing some code here. Shouldn't this be using a material UI methods withStyles, useStyles, or makeStyles?

Comment: Mostly there. It misses the border color for a hover state. You also need  '&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before': {  borderColor: selectColor, }' in the select: {} overrides.  (from a partial answer given below by @Sarah Cheatham)

Answer (score 31):

I don't know why setting the color of the border and icon got so complicated. In any case, the answer above didn't help me with setting the icon color. Eventually, I found the solution via this code:

text color: white
border: rgba(228, 219, 233, 0.25)
icon (arrow): white

```
  <Select
          // IconComponent={() => <ArrowDropDownIcon style={{marginRight:10,pointerEvents:'none'}}/>}
          labelStyle={{ color: '#ff0000' }}
          sx={{
            color: "white",
            '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
              borderColor: 'rgba(228, 219, 233, 0.25)',
            },
            '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
              borderColor: 'rgba(228, 219, 233, 0.25)',
            },
            '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
              borderColor: 'rgba(228, 219, 233, 0.25)',
            },
            '.MuiSvgIcon-root ': {
              fill: "white !important",
            }
          }}
          labelId="select-filter-by-field-labe;"
          id="select-filter-by-field"
          value={'some value'}
        >
          
        </Select>
```

Comment: Is labelStyle supposed to change the color of the label (like the text color of the label)? Because if so, it is not working for me :(

Answer (score 5):

You can change the border color and SVG icon color of a MUI `<Select>` component using the following declaration:

```
<Select
    sx={{
        height: '2.5rem',
        color: 'white',
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'white'
        },
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
            color: 'white'
        }
    }}
>
```

Comment: This solution works with Autocomplete with below setting:
`
"& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: "green !important",
},
`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the bottom border color with the following code. Hope this helps you.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  select: {
    "&:before": {
      borderColor: "red"
    }
  }
});

const MySelect = ({ classes }) => (
  <Select value="1" className={classes.select}>
    <MenuItem value="1">Option 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="2">Option 2</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="3">Option 3</MenuItem>
  </Select>
);
```

[Example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxm61jpr09)

Comment: Thanks, this works for coloring the underline border, but it stays dark while the component is in focus.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<Select
    sx={{
        "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
            color: "white"
        }
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access input (and the underline) like so:

```
<Select
  autoWidth
  classes={{
    root: styles.root,
    select: styles.select
  }}
  displayEmpty
  input={
    <Input
      classes={{
        underline: styles.underline
      }}
    />
  }
  onChange={this.onChange}
  value=""
>
```

Comment: make more sense for input, but what about icon color ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select: {
   '&:before': {
        borderColor: 'var(--galaxy-blue)',
    },
    '&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before': {
        borderColor: 'var(--galaxy-blue)',
    }
},

<Select
   className={classes.select}
   value={selected}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: +1 for getting the '&:hover:not(.Mu-disabled):before': clause, which was missing in the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import {
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  OutlinedInput as MuiOutlinedInput,
} from "@material-ui/core";
    
const OutlinedInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
  notchedOutline: {
    borderColor: "white !important",
  },
}))(MuiOutlinedInput);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  select: {
    color: "white",
  },
  icon: { color: "white" },
  label: { color: "white" },
}));

function Component() {
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel id="labelId" className={classes.label}>
        Label
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="labelId"
        classes={{
          select: classes.select,
          icon: classes.icon,
        }}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Label" />}
      >
        <MenuItem>A</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>B</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a root class available in MUI documentation, we can easily override that, for arrow and border outline

```
<Select variant='outlined' sx={{'.MuiSelect-icon': {
        color: 'white'
    },
  ".MuiSelect-outlined":{
        color: 'white'
  }}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it this:

I added the .css file into react file:

```
import './index.css';
```

```
<Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
    id="demo-simple-select-standard"
    value={selectedRegion}
    onChange={handleChangeSelectOption}
    label="region"
    className="select-options-navbar-main-color"
>
    {regionList.map((item)=>{
         return <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
    })}
</Select>
```

and at the end the most important file `.css` file:

```
:root{
  --select-options-navbar-main-color: white;
}

.select-options-navbar-main-color div{
  color: var(--select-options-navbar-main-color) !important;
}
.select-options-navbar-main-color::before {
  border-color: var(--select-options-navbar-main-color) !important;
  
}

.select-options-navbar-main-color::after {
  border-color: var(--select-options-navbar-main-color) !important;
  
}

.select-options-navbar-main-color:not(.Mui-disabled):hover::before {
  border-color: var(--select-options-navbar-main-color) !important;
  
}

.select-options-navbar-main-color svg{
  fill: var(--select-options-navbar-main-color) !important;
}
```