# How to change the underline and label color of Material-UI <Select/>

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I used this demo to change the colours of some input fields: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color

I was wondering if anyone had a similar demo for when they've changed the colour of their select components from material UI? Or some instructions on how to go about doing it (I've looked at the docs already but am struggling to follow them).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://codesandbox.io/s/vt71p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of Select component's border and arrow icon Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387085/change-color-of-select-components-border-and-arrow-icon-material-ui)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your select with `<FormControl />` and also add `<InputLabel />` as `<Select />` sibling. 
After that, override InputLabel root class and also provide className to select component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  underline: {
    color: 'red' ,
    '&::after': {
      borderBottom: '2px solid red'
    },
    '&::before': {
      borderBottom: '2px solid yellow'
    }
  },
  inputLabelRoot: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel classes={{root: classes.inputLabelRoot}}>Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.underline}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]