# Material-UI: Select border color on hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am able to change the

"before" [image]

and "after" [image]

border color to grey in dark mode. However, when I hover my mouse to the "Select" field, it become black.
[image]

How can I change that? Thank you very much!

Resources:

[Change color of Select component's border and arrow icon Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387085/change-color-of-select-components-border-and-arrow-icon-material-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border-bottom style of the `Input` changes when you hover it. This is how you override the border color:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    "& .MuiInput-underline:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before": {
      borderColor: "blue"
    }
  },
  select: {
    "&:before": {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
  }
}));
```

#### Usage

```js
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel>Age</InputLabel>
  <Select className={classes.select} {...props}
  >
    <MenuItem value="">
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66979649/material-ui-select-border-color]

Comment: Thank you very much! I just implemented as per your suggestion and it is working perfectly fine.