# Change color of the IconComponent of Material UI's Select Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

For my project, I'm using MUI's Select Component with the *LanguageIcon* as the *IconComponent*.
What I'm trying to do is turn this icon white (it's black per default), but I can't get it to work.

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387085/change-color-of-select-components-border-and-arrow-icon-material-ui) solution, but it won't work for me.
`import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';` throws "Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/styles'" and on their website it says *@mui/styles* is deprecated.

This is what I currently have:

```ts
import * as React from 'react';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, {SelectChangeEvent} from "@mui/material/Select";
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router';
import LanguageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Language';

const LocaleSelect: FunctionComponent = () => {

  const router = useRouter()
  const {locale, locales, pathname, asPath, query} = router;

  const handleLocaleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>) => {
    router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, { locale: event.target.value})
  }

  return(
    <FormControl
      variant='standard'
      sx={{ m: 1, maxWidth: 32 }}
      color="primary" >
        
      <Select
        disableUnderline
        labelId="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
        value={locale?.toLocaleUpperCase()}
        onChange={handleLocaleChange}
        autoWidth
        IconComponent={LanguageIcon} >
        {locales?.map((l) => {
          return <MenuItem key={l} value={l}>
            {l.toLocaleUpperCase()}</MenuItem>;
        })}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default LocaleSelect
```

This makes it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCEy.png).

I managed to make the globe white by using

```ts
IconComponent={() => <LanguageIcon htmlColor='white'/>}
```

but that moves the globe to the [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q90v.png).

Any help would be fantastic; either by making the globe white or by moving it to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
 <LanguageIcon 
      htmlColor="white" 
      sx={{ position: "absolute", left: ".5rem",cursor:'pointer',zIndex:-1 }}
 />
```

Position absolute makes it easy to align the icon where you want but the icon becomes un-clickable. To solve this I added cursor:pointer which partially solved the issue but wasn't able to click yet. Hence I reduced the z-index.

Reducing the z-index works because, clicking on icon actually clicks the parent and then displays the options.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped!